# Disable word completion dialog when pressing escape in Safari

Tags: macos, mac, safari

Behavior:

1. Load Safari 5.0 on mac.
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search for some text.
3. Type something, and find it on the page.
4. Hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel the search.
5. Irritatingly, get word completion menu rather than canceling.

Is there any way to make <kbd>esc</kbd> cancel the search, like it used to with Safari 4.0, instead of pulling up a word completion dialog? It's very annoying. Failing that, what's the best way to cancel the search with the keyboard?

Note: this also happens in any text field, the search box, the location bar etc.

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled? I'm running Safari 5.0 (6533.16) for Mac OS X 10.6, following your steps precisely, and I'm exiting the search rather than getting spell-check.

Comment: nope. I thought it might be glims, but it turns out it's not. I have removed all extensions, but I'm still getting this behavior.

Comment: By spell check menu, do you mean word completion menu? I get that with option-Esc.

Comment: yep, word completion menu. but no option required...

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I eventually traced it to some emacs-style custom keybindings I had installed.

Check if this file exists and delete it, then log out and in again:

```
~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the above commenters, I can't replicate this either (option-escape is what works for me), but have a look in the Keyboard section of System Preferences - under Keyboard Shortcuts you can specify extra keyboard shortcuts - perhaps you have an extra Service installed?